# On post request req.query returns empty dictionary in express node

Tags: node.js, express, web, post

I want to get post query values to create a new row in the database. But in req.query It don't works. I also tried with body-parser but it also didn't worked.
The code

```
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, './static/image/')
    },
    filename: (req, file, cb) => {
        const { originalname } = file;
        cb(null, originalname)
        filename = originalname;
    }
})
const upload = multer({ storage: storage })

app.post('/admin/song/create', upload.single('file'),  async(req, res) => {
    console.log(req.query)
    res.redirect('/admin')
})
```

And The Client-Side Code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-AYmEC3Yw5cVb3ZcuHtOA93w35dYTsvhLPVnYs9eStHfGJvOvKxVfELGroGkvsg+p" crossorigin="anonymous"/>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
    input{
        margin: 10px;

    }
</style>
<div class="container" id="conT">

    <form action="/admin/song/create" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file" class="btn-success btn">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Name" name="name" >
    <input type="text" placeholder="Movie Or Album Name" name="movie_or_album_name" >
    <input type="text" placeholder="Description" name="description" >
    <input type="text" placeholder="URL" name="urls" >
    <input type="number" placeholder="year" name="description" >
    <button type="submit" class="btn-success btn">Submit</button>
    </form>

</div>


</body>
</html>
```

And I also did set the middleware for body-parser but It also don't work. But It does work with GET requests. Why It doesn't work with the POST request.
If Anyone knows Please respond. It will be helpful.

### ***Thank You Very Much***

Comment: Please include your request, e.g. as a `curl`.

Comment: I didn't understood . Actually I am new in this language and also in this website

Comment: Show the code of client-side.

Comment: I updated the question. Please check It out

Answer (score 0):

`req.query` [documentation](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.query):

> This property is an object containing a property for each **query string parameter** in the route.

What you're looking for is `req.body`.

Also, since you seem to use file upload via `multer` and may want to access that data, `multer` [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer):

> Multer adds a body object and **a file or files object to the request object**. The body object contains the values of the text fields of the form, the file or files object contains the files uploaded via the form.

Since you're using `multer.single`, you should have a `req.file` (singular).